# Ignore a property in Dto from RequestBody base on endpoint (use one Dto for two purpose)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto

I have a Coupon Table in the database so there are CouponEntity and CouponDto in the application. My question is about handling two endpoints with one Dto. for example, I have create and update endpoints, both of them use CouponDto. There is a business role that I can't update `code` property of the coupon entity. How to ignore it if the client passes this property in the request?

If I use `@JsonIgnore`, the property will be ignored in both the endpoints that I need to get it in create API. I used `groups` for validations and separate validations from each other, but `@JsonIgnore` can not be set sometimes.

For create a coupon:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public ResponseEntity<?> createCoupon(@RequestBody CouponCodeDTO couponCodeDTO) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(couponService.create(couponCodeDTO));
}
```

For update a coupon:

```
@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateCoupon(
    @PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody CouponCodeDTO couponCodeDTO
) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(couponService.update(id, couponCodeDTO));
}
```

And CouponDto:

```
public class CouponCodeDto extends BaseDto<Integer> {

    @NotBlank
    private String code;

    private Integer availableCount;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDate startDate;
    
   ...
}
```

Comment: Try using @JsonFilter and FilterProvider.Check this link as well - https://dzone.com/articles/spring-web-service-response-filtering

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya Thanks for your response, but the article is about filtering response and I want to filter ```request``` that sure an unwanted property does not update.

Comment: In general, your DTOs shouldn't "escape" your controller layer; the controller layer's exact job is to translate between the HTTP side of things and your internal data model. In the case where the controller handles mapping the DTO onto the business object, it's pretty easy to configure your mapper (e.g., MapStruct) to ignore specific fields on the incoming objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@JsonView` to specify the field you want to serialize/deserialize per view and specify view on the endpoint.

```
public class Views {
    interface Update {}
    interface Create extends Update {}
}

public class CouponCodeDto extends BaseDto<Integer> {

    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.Create.class)
    private String code;

    @JsonView(Views.Update.class)
    private Integer availableCount;

    @NotNull
    @JsonView(Views.Update.class)
    private LocalDate startDate;
    
   ...
}
```

And use on request body of the endpoint

```
@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateCoupon(@PathVariable Long id, 
                   @JsonView(Views.Update.class) @RequestBody CouponCodeDTO couponCodeDTO) {

@PostMapping("/create")
public ResponseEntity<?> createCoupon(
                   @JsonView(Views.Create.class) @RequestBody CouponCodeDTO couponCodeDTO) {
```

Here you find details

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems you are setting a view on the response of the controller, I need to filter ```request``` that sure an unwanted property does not update.

Comment: @MahmoodKohansal It will work on both when serialize and deserialize. Did you try ? You can read official doc of `@JsonView` [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html)

Comment: I try the code and search @JsonView for control request input, I found that putting annotation before @RequestMapping annotations control and filter responses, for control request, @JsonView annotation must be put before @RequestBody, something like :

 ```@PutMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateCoupon(
            @PathVariable Long id,
            @JsonView(Views.Update.class)
            @RequestBody CouponCodeDTO couponCodeDTO
    ) {```

please edit the answer to accept it.

Comment: @MahmoodKohansal Thanks, totally missed the point, updated.